# How do I await action response in a loop c#

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, async-await, action

We have a collection we want to loop through which we need to make a service call for each item in the collection and await the response before executing the next service call in the collection.

The issue is that I am unable to await the response before executing the next item in the collection, I did manage to get this to work by triggering the result using TaskCompletionSource but this seems dirty. Is there a better way to do this?

I have tried using 'Func oftype Task' but couldn't seem to get this to work.

```
public async Task<bool> PerformRTV(string policyId)
      {
        if (!Instance.RTVDone)
        {
            var result = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            PerformValuation(policyId, resp =>
            {
                if (!(resp.Error is null))
                {
                    ErrorService.LogError(resp.Error);
                    result.SetResult(false);
                    return;
                }

                if (!resp.Result)
                {
                    result.SetResult(false);
                    return;
                }

                result.SetResult(true);
                return;

            });

            return await result.Task;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }


    private void PerformValuation(string policyId, Action<#########CompletedEventArgs> response)
    {
        Service.HookResponseHandlerToServiceEvent(_portfolioServiceClient, nameof(_portfolioServiceClient.#########Completed), response);
        _portfolioServiceClient.#########RTVAsync(policyId, ApplicationSettings.Authentication.TPCodeID);
    }
```

In a nutshell I am calling the PerformRTV in a loop and want to wait the response before calling PerformRTV with the next item in the loop.

Comment: If the API you're calling doesn't support tasks, there's nothing dirty about using `TaskCompletionSource`, that's exactly what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, TaskCompletionSource is not dirty. I think it's the way to go.

I would just return the Task itself, instead of await it in this method *(not a async method)*. The decision of awaiting could be done a level up. You might want to await multiple calls. And for returning `true` directly, you could use the `Task.FromResult()`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, the API doesn't support tasks so I am happy with this although I think moving this a level up might be a good call.

Comment: If the API doesn't support tasks, you could create it yourself.Just use a TaskCompletionSource and run the API call on a Task.Run.